# How to redirect to Battery health page in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, battery, ios12

We are using the following code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Battery"]];
```

But the code doesn't work for me in iOS 12.0

Comment: This is private API;  If you use it (or any replacement) your app will be rejected during app review

Answer (score 1):

You have two steps:

1. You must configure the URL Schemes in your project. You will find it in *Target*, *Info*, and *URL Scheme*. Once there, just type prefs.
2. Later, just write the code with the URL path of the preference needed. In this case, it was the battery path.

**URL Schemes**

```
Launch from Widget (Prefs:) :-  Prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE
Launch from App (App-prefs:) :- App-prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE

Swift 1.2

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"Prefs:root=BATTERY_USAG")!)

Swift 3.0

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"App-prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE")!)

Objective C

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Prefs:root=BATTERY_USAG"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `prefs` to `App-Prefs` for iOS 10. Above code works for iOS 8,9,10. Please refer below code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=General&path=Battery"]];
```

Above 10.0 it is not possible to redirect battery usage screen because above method is deprecated after iOS 10.0